# Shorten series of if and elif

Tags: python

How would I shorten a code that involves a series of if and elif? Like if I wanted to shorten the code below. Is it possible I could use a list and select preset value from that list?

```
def mfunction():
    print("The following results shown are specifically for \nmales, as you stated you were in the beginning.")
    if (rb < 5.9 and rb > 4.3):
            print("Red blood cell levels are normal.")
    elif (rb > 5.9):
            print("Red blood cell levels indicate: Dehydration, \nheart disease, or polycythemia vera")
    else:
            print("Red blood cell levels indicate: Amenia.")
    if (wb < 11000 and wb > 45000):
            print("White blood cells are at normal level.")
    elif (wb > 11000):
            print("White blood cell levels indicate: Stress, infection.")
    else:
            print("White blood cell levels indicate: Viral infection \nin bone marrow, or HIV.")
```

Comment: sorry for the ugly code, I didn't know it would post like that.

Comment: Rather than apologizing for your formatting, instead [edit] your post to fix it.

Comment: There are other ways to organize this code, but I don't think any of them make it shorter.  If you had a large number of different metrics, I'd suggest putting them all in a dictionary, but for two I don't think it's worth the complexity.  The bigger problem with this function is that it doesn't take `rb` and `wb` as arguments.

Comment: You can simplify the chained comparisons in a couple of your `if` and `elif` statements - for instance, instead of `if (rb < 5.9 and rb > 4.3):`, you could put in `if 5.9 > rb > 4.3:`. You could also get rid of the `else`s by instead storing that message as the default, and print at the end; so, rather than having a `print` in each `if` or `elif` statement, you just set a string to a different value.